# How to display comments of current node in a view

Tags: views, comments

I would like to display comments of the current node in a view. The reason for doing so is that I want the comments to be neatly displayed in a table and views seems to be an easiest way to do so than messing with theme template etc. (I am new to drupal)

I have created a comment view and selected comment: nid as a filter selector. How do I provide the "current NID" as the argument for the filter? I have tried Comment:nid is equal to "current" but this does not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a contextual filter.  In your view, remove comment:nid from the Filter Criteria.

Next, on the far right, under "Advanced", add a "Contextual Filters" and select comment: nid there.

[image]

In the configuration options, under WHEN THE FILTER IS *NOT* AVAILABLE, select "Provide Default Value".  From the Type dropdown, select "Content ID from URL".

[image]

Click Apply, save your view, and add the block as normal.