# Search in comments of specific content type

Tags: 7, comments

I'm looking for a module that provides the possibility to filter/search in comments.

When there is content of the content type = `Proposal` you can comment on it. There's a good change that there will be **50 comments or more**. Now I would like to have a search box *beneath my content*, *above my comments* that filter the comments when you **search** for a string.

I would also need to **filter the comments** for ex. between dates, by username, by number of votes, ... .

I've searched the internet but couldn't find anything that provides this functionality.

Has anybody ever needed this and which module you used or how did you approach this?

It's something like this I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to enable [vote up/down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) and voting api module enabled
Then enable voting for 'Proposal' content type mentioned in the image

[image]

Now import the below code mentioned in views.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'proposal_comments';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'comment';
$view->human_name = 'Proposal comments';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test comments';
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['link_display'] = 'custom_url';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'comment';
/* Relationship: Comment: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Relationship: Comment: Votes */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['id'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['field'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_vote']['current_user'] = 0;
/* Relationship: Comment: Vote results */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['id'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['field'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => '',
  'function' => '',
);
/* Field: Comment: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['id'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['field'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Comment: Comment */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['id'] = 'comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['table'] = 'field_data_comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_body']['field'] = 'comment_body';
/* Sort criterion: Comment: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Comment: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'name_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['expose']['label'] = 'Author';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['expose']['operator'] = 'name_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['expose']['identifier'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Comment: Comment (comment_body) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['id'] = 'comment_body_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['table'] = 'field_data_comment_body';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['field'] = 'comment_body_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'comment_body_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['expose']['label'] = 'Comment (comment_body)';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['expose']['operator'] = 'comment_body_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['expose']['identifier'] = 'comment_body_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['comment_body_value']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Comment: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'created_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['expose']['label'] = 'Post date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['expose']['operator'] = 'created_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['expose']['identifier'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['created']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Votes: Value */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['id'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['table'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['field'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['relationship'] = 'votingapi_vote';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['expose']['label'] = 'Value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['expose']['operator'] = 'value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['expose']['identifier'] = 'vote';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['value']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test-comments';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['link_url'] = 'demo';
```

It will create a block in the admin/structure/block mentioned 
 in the below image. Assign it to 'Proposal' content type.
[image]

It will be displayed under proposal node view page this way

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpfull! Do you know how I can hide the standard comments?

Comment: Just create node--proposal.tpl.php and use hide($content['comments']); on the top or you can alter it in custom module using hook_preprocess_node()

Comment: you can hide it in content type using comment setting tab for new content. For already created content you need to hide it manually on the tab

Answer (score 1):

I would look to put the comments in a view that you can add exposed filters to for dates, username, etc. See [How to display comments of current node in a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80525/how-to-display-comments-of-current-node-in-a-view)

Comment: But I still need the possibility to comment on comments + vote on comments, ..

Comment: I think you will still be able to if you render rows as 'Rendered Entity' with the 'Display links' option.

Answer (score 1):

1) Edit your content type.

2) Under comments setting section, search for "Default comment setting for new            content" drop down.

3) Select "Hidden" from drop down.

4) Click on save.